# large Spaces in documents

Tags: white-space

please I'm new in latex. I have a problem with my paper which is the existing of a lot of white spaces between paragraphs, table and its comments and so on. I don't know how to fix it. I tried to use the following code but
the same problem.

```
\makeatletter
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
    {-10.5dd plus-4pt minus-2pt}{10.5dd}
    {\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {-10.5dd plus-4pt minus-2pt}{10.5dd}
    {\normalsize\upshape}} 
\makeatother
```

Comment: This code does not explain anything, please show us an example of a document that  generates large spaces. I'm guessing (1) large align constructions or (2) excessive use of the `[H]` float specifier.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Did you think that the problem is because of the excessive use [H] because for all figures and tables I have used it? [h]make a lot of problems

Comment: You could try `\raggedbottom` but I think that you will have to re-think about your float specifications.

Comment: Many thanks the problem was fixed by replacing [H] by [th!] and add specific parameters at the beginning of the document

Comment: Sadly we see a lot of new users throw themselves at `[H]` because they don't appreciate or understand floats. Now you know why `[H]` is hardly ever the solution and most often end up being a problem

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because is solved bycomments.